# java-mysql program

Tags: java

i have a table - emp_details in mysql
i want to seatch an employ's id number in java.
if it is in the table , then show all the details of employee.
otherwise display an error message.
how i do this

Comment: Another poorly-disguised homework question.

Comment: @skaffman +1 , ans so my answer

Answer (score 2):

[Using **JDBC**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)
Here is an example You can build your solution from it.

```
   Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
    try {
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total);
      }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
      JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
      stmt.close();
    }
```

Comment: iam taking values to resultset

Comment: then how i compare the values

Comment: ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Employee_ID FROM `employee_details ");

Comment: if(keyboard value!=)
    {
     
    }
     else{
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee_details where Employee_ID='"+strEmpId+"'");

if(rs1.next()) {
 System.out.println("Emp ID : " + rs1.getString(1));
 System.out.println("Emp Name : " + rs1.getString(2));
 System.out.println("Emp Salary : " + rs1.getString(3));
} else {
  System.out.println("Emp ID not found");
}
```

If you want to know more about SQL just go through [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)